# SQL using variable in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can copy a row and change the value of a single field in the same table like this which works perfectly fine:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (foo,bar)
    SELECT foo,'new bar'
    FROM myTable
    WHERE rowIndex=5
```

But I'd like to replace `'new bar'` with an inline variable. I have tried this to no avail:

```
DECLARE @Bar varchar(50) = 'new bar'
INSERT INTO myTable (foo,bar)
    SELECT foo,@Bar
    FROM myTable
    WHERE rowIndex=5
```

I just get thrown an error that says `@Bar` is an invalid column.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: MySQL or SQL? You have tagged them both but SQL is suggested in title.

Comment: You have this tagged with SQL Server 2008 and MySQL. Which are you really using? This is valid syntax in SQL2K8.

Comment: Fixed the tags; I'm using MSSQL 2008.

Comment: Syntax looks OK. Are you executing both the `DECLARE` and the `INSERT` in the same batch?

Comment: Yes, both queries are in the same batch.

Comment: Is this the exact code you are running, in Management Studio? Or are you constructing this code in a different language/application?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Please copy/paste from Management Studio.

Comment: No @niktrs, that shouldn't be required in the original code sample. Did you try it? This will actually put single quotes around the value that is stored in the table.

Comment: @Jesse, I think you are getting that error because you are using double quotes, e.g. DECLARE @Bar VARCHAR(50) = "new bar" ... see why it is important to show the ***EXACT*** code you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case you thought that Yuck's answer had an issue with the temp table here it is with  a non-temp table

```
CREATE TABLE 
         myTable 
  (foo varchar (50),
   bar varchar(50) ,
   rowIndex int identity)

SET identity_INSERT MyTable on 
INSERT INTO myTable  (foo, bar, rowIndex ) values ('foo','bar', 50)
SET identity_INSERT MyTable oFF

DECLARE @Bar varchar(50) = 'new bar'
INSERT INTO myTable (foo,bar)
    SELECT foo,@Bar
    FROM myTable
    WHERE rowIndex=50

    select foo, bar , rowIndex
    from myTable
    Drop table mytable
```

Results in

```
foo bar     rowIndex
--- ------- --------
foo bar     50
foo new bar 51
```

This also works in c# using the SQLDataClient

```
using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=yoursever;Initial  Catalog=yourDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
{ 
    cnn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = @"DECLARE @Bar varchar(50) = 'new bar' 
                        INSERT INTO myTable (foo,bar)   
                        SELECT foo,
                             @Bar    
                         FROM 
                           myTable    
                         WHERE rowIndex=50";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran this code on my laptop - SQL Server 2K8 v10.0.1600

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable (
  rowIndex Int IDENTITY(1, 1),
  foo VarChar(10),
  bar VarChar(50)
);

DECLARE @Bar VarChar(50) = 'new bar';
INSERT INTO #MyTable (foo, bar)
    SELECT foo, @Bar
    FROM #MyTable
    WHERE rowIndex = 5;

DROP TABLE #MyTable;
```

It works fine if executed as a single batch and is (other than the temporary table) identical to yours.

Comment: I just keep getting thrown an error saying that @Bar is not a valid column. Ugh.

Comment: @Jesse: How are you running this query? Are you using SSMS? Is this code the only code in your query window?

Comment: Silly me, the error was being thrown on a different statement. I'm trying to set the value of `@Bar` like so `SET @Bar='new bar'` **after** I declare it. MSSQL won't let me set a default value during the variable declaration so I have to do it this way; but that's just it...`@Bar` isn't a column. How can I assign a value to it then?

Comment: @Jesse, there is a HUGE difference between single quotes and double quotes. I feel bad for all of the people who have wasted time chasing wild geese when you didn't bother posting the actual code you were using. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
DECLARE @Bar VarChar(50) = 'new bar'
```

Can you try? :

```
DECLARE @Bar VarChar(50) 
SET @Bar = 'new bar'
```

Comment: I have tried that (because I would get an error if I tried the former) and it appears that the real culprit of the error is the line `SET @Bar = 'new bar'`. MSSQL thinks I'm trying to `SET` a column value instead of the variable...

Comment: @Jesse: `SET @Bar = "new bar"` gives me `Invalid column name 'new bar'`. `SET @Bar = 'new bar'` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

for stuff like that you should be using `Stored Procedures`

Sorry this might be my experiences but i have never seen an insert SELECT before?

*MYSQL Example*

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE InsertInto_myTable(
        IN Bar              VARCHAR(11)
    )
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO `myTable` (foo,bar) SELECT `foo`,@Bar FROM `myTable` WHERE rowIndex = 5;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Then once this is done you just call `CALL InsertInto_myTable('new bar')`

*MSSQL Example*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE InsertInto_myTable(
    Bar varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO myTable (foo,bar) 
    SELECT foo,@Bar
    FROM myTable
    WHERE rowIndex=5;
END
```

Use
`EXECUTE InsertInto_myTable('new bar');`

Comment: Copy the code from the answer I've provided. It works fine in SSMS Query Analyzer if you run all three statements in one batch.

Comment: Thanks any ways you have made me learn some thing new with the insert select stuff any ways